# How to refetch a query without a mutation

Tags: reactjs, apollo

After finishing a server call I want to refetch a specific query. The Apollo API has an option for mutations that lets you refetch but I want to refetch WITHOUT the mutation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to manually firing a client.query ?
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#manual-query

The client variable is also available when you export your apolloClient.

Comment: and what if I'd like to just use a query name like for `refetch` and so exactly same query binded to UI will be re-executed?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little bit old but here is the link to the apollo documentation that explain how to do it:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/refetching/#clientrefetchqueries

Basically you can just use the apollo client instance and call the following method:

```
await client.refetchQueries({
  include: [SOME_QUERY],
});
```

Answer (score -3):

if I have understood your question correctly, you could use [QueryResult.refetch](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#render-prop). here is some dirty code:

```
setInterval(() => {
  props.data.refetch({
    take: 10,
    skip: 0,
  }, );
}, 2000);
```

where `data` is the default name of a query result injected into the `props` of a component by `graphql(...)`